# how to structure firebase database to get results like relational databases

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase Cloud Firestore for my Android and iOS apps. I am stuck with how to structure my database.

Basically I have an "organization" collection that contains many users, and for every user, I want to save attendance time and leave time for every day.

**The problem is I want to generate reports that allow me to get every day-attendance for each user, single-day attendance for all users, and all days attendance for all users.**

so I tried this: inside the user I would have an "attendance" collection then each document is Unix timestamp of that day (to make sure that it's unique). then save fields like attend_time and leave_time...etc. the path is like that "/organization/android/users/3PRs42gRFzZQhLKcUhpf4wPMRV43/attendance/1590271200"

then I needed to get attendance for a single day for all users, so I did this: now I have another path "/organization/android/attendance" and inside the attendance, I store the Unix timestamp of the day, then the user ID then his attendance. and now I am saving attendance twice.

but I still can't get attendance for all days for all users!
this would be easy in Relational Database like SQL. any idea how to do it in firebase?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track attendance across all users, you're looking for a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). This allows you to query documents from all collections named `attendance`.

Since a query in Firestore can only see data in the collection(s) it queries, you may have to duplicate some data from parent collections (your `users` and `organizations`) into each attendance document to allow the query. This type of data duplication is quite normal in NoSQL databases too.

Finally: if you need to perform many ad-hoc queries, you might want to consider using a database for those that is more suited to that use-case. For example, it is quite common to use Firestore to handle the direct-to-client interactions that require scaling to massive number of users, but then use BigQuery for the ad-hoc querying of that data. There is even a Firebase Extension that [automatically exports to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export) to make this easier.